# How to use a callback array as the handler for a Sails.js route?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

When using Express, it is possible to attach a callback array to a route like this:

```
app.get('/path', thisIsAnArrayOfFunctions);
```

And then, when making a request to `http://route_to_server/path` each function inside `thisIsAnArrayOfFunctions` is called.

*Exactly* how does that routing behaviour works in express? is it just an iteration through `thisIsAnArrayOfFunctions`, passing the arguments `req`, `res` and `next`?

Is it possible to achieve a simple implementation in Sails for this?

I know it works if I attach the routing as an express middleware, but I want to know if there's a solution using the Sails' (version 0.9.8) controller structure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sails-y way of chaining functions to a route is by using [policies](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/config.policies.md).  The idea is that your controller code should be the last stop in handling your route.  Anything that might modify the response (like a login check, or something that could change the params) should be implemented as a policy, which is middleware that can call `next` or send a response directly.  Policies are mapped to controller actions, and multiple policies can be applied to a single action  (or to all actions in a controller).

Docs for policies are [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/config.policies.md).

Comment: thanks, it worked as I needed it to. It's a great way of taking complexity away from the controllers and re-utilize code; just a question: why are they called `policies` instead or `middleware` or something similar?

Comment: Two reasons: first, because they were originally used mainly for access control, and second, to avoid confusion with Express middleware (which you can also add to Sails projects via config/express.js).