# How to use an error-handler callback in a Sails.js policy?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160043/how-to-use-a-callback-array-as-the-handler-for-a-sails-js-route), I've found that I can add a callback array to an endpoint in a sails app like this:

file: `/api/policies/somepolicy.js`

```
module.exports = thisIsAnArrayOfCallbacks;
```

This works ok while each member of `thisIsAnArrayOfCallbacks` is a `function` which accepts `req`, `res`, and `next` as arguments. The controller call executes all the functions in the array and the expected result is obtained in a normal flow.

But when using an `errorHandler` callback (like the one in [this example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/blob/master/examples/express2/oauth2.js#L142)) which takes an additional `err` parameter, it doesn't work as expected: the express-only version `app.get('/path', thisIsAnArrayOfCallbacks)` allows the `errorHandler` to fetch the exception and report a proper response to the client, but when using the sails way, the `errorHandler` function isn't called and the exception is thrown in the response.

How could I fetch the `err` parameter or catch the exception occurred in one of the functions of `thisIsAnArrayOfCallbacks` to send a proper response (a custom one is preferred) to the client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct in that policies can't be defined as error callbacks; they're solely route-handling middleware and are actually bound to each individual route that they are applied to.  Ideally, you'd catch any errors within the policy functions themselves using `try/catch` and send a response using something like `res.forbidden()`, `res.badRequest()`, `res.serverError()`, etc.  In Sails v0.10 you can make any custom response you want and store it in the `api/responses` folder.

If you really want to implement a catch-all error handler in Sails you have two choices: either override the default 500 handler (in Sails v0.10 this is in `/api/responses/serverError`, in v0.9.x it's `config/500.js`), or (in v0.10) create custom Express middleware and load it using `sails.config.express.loadMiddleware`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939832/adding-jquery-file-upload-middleware-to-sails-js/21946577#21946577) for details on the second option, and remember to add your custom error handler *after* the router and *before* (or in place of) the 500 handler.