# How do you catch all errors in SailsJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm new to Node and Sails and have been struggling with this problem for a couple of weeks now.  I need to log (eventually to a file or database) all errors that occur in our Sails app.  I have found a couple of answers that come close to solving this, but none seem to work 100%.  I have setup things based off of the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182326/how-to-use-an-error-handler-callback-in-a-sails-js-policy)

When using Sails v0.9.16 I setup my logging in the config/500.js file, but when using test code...

```
t.t;
```

... in my controller,  Sails just prints out "ReferenceError: t is not defined".  It never goes to 500.js.  In Sails v0.10.0-rc5 the same test code will get to my custom 500 middleware (shown below).

Problem is in Sails v0.10.0-rc5 it appears that the middleware Router handles 400 error message before getting to my custom 400 middleware.

We have not committed to which version we are going to use, but getting this to work in one or the other would probably make up our minds.

So how do I get all errors that happen?  If I am on the right track, what am I missing to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Not much code to show for v0.9.16...I don't think I changed anything other than adding a sails.log in the 500.js file...

Below is the custom middleware setup for v0.10.0-rc5 ...

```
    loadMiddleware: function(app, defaultMiddleware, sails) {

    // Use the middleware in the correct order
        app.use(defaultMiddleware.startRequestTimer);
        app.use(defaultMiddleware.cookieParser);
        app.use(defaultMiddleware.session);
        app.use(defaultMiddleware.bodyParser);
        app.use(defaultMiddleware.handleBodyParserError);
        app.use(defaultMiddleware.methodOverride);
        app.use(defaultMiddleware.poweredBy);

        app.use(defaultMiddleware.router); //400s do not make it past this...
        app.use(defaultMiddleware.www);
        app.use(defaultMiddleware.favicon);

        app.use(function(req, res, next ) {
            sails.log("400 error caught in middleware - " + err.stack);         
            next();
        });

        app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
            sails.log("500 error caught in middleware - " + err.stack);
            next(err);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Sails v0.10, you have [custom responses](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/CustomResponses.md) to handle errors, so you don't need to provide custom middleware as in your example.  By default, most errors (i.e. those not specifically triggered by `res.forbidden()`, `res.notFound()` or another handler) will be served by the `serverError` response that lives in `api/responses/serverError.js`.  You can customize this to do whatever you like.

If you've upgraded a v0.9 app to v0.10, you might not have the `api/responses` folder.  No problem; just use `sails new whatever` in an empty directory to generate a new v0.10 project and copy the `api/responses` folder from the new project to your old one!

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for answering so quickly!  I do have the api/rsponse director.  I was hesitant to put the error logging in the responses, thinking that if an other error occurred while the original was bubbling up I would end up missing it. If this is the proper place to put logging then that solves everything.  Is this possible in v0.9? The only way I was able to get into 500.js was to use res.serverError().

Comment: v0.9 doesn't have custom responses, so it's much easier to do in v0.10.  At this point, pretty much everything that can be caught by Sails is being funneled into `res.serverError`, so customizing `serverError.js` should get you what you need.  One exception was errors that occurred when rendering a view, but that [got patched today](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/commit/fc2284573122d7a5417954c5d3e6117a0b5c088f), so it you want *full* coverage you can [pull the latest Sails](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails) from Github.

Comment: Thank you very much for you time and thorough answer!