# Sails.js adding error domains

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node.js-domains

This is basically a follow up question to an earlier question ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481572/how-do-you-catch-all-errors-in-sailsjs)).

We set up our error handling based off of the response files found in `api/responses/`.  This seems to work for almost all cases, but there does seem to be errors that can happen that do not get to the responses, and crash Sails.  After looking around we found a spot in the Sails code (v0.10.0-rc6) with a comment:

```
// TODO: Add support for error domains..?
```

This commend is found in `sails/lib/hooks/http/initialize.js` in `sails.on()`, this is where Sails binds routes to the internal Express router.

If we wanted to add error domains code, is this a good spot?

Comment: What errors are you seeing that crash Sails?

Comment: We are testing using throw error, in a model's afterCreate.  This will cause the server to crash.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok--just FYI, rather than throwing an error, you can pass the error to `afterCreate`'s callback.  Then the error will be passed back to the `create` callback as the first argument.  In the case of blueprints, this lets Sails handle the error without crashing.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  This is just for testing.  We want to make sure we cover everything, including unhandled errors from async calls. I have setup some test code that uses clusters and wraps sails.lift inside a domain.  This catches the test throw error, but shutting down sails with sails.lower() (using example code from [link](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) doesn't seem to work quite right.  It times out rather than closing.